# how to split string in PostgreSQL by making procedure

Tags: postgresql

I tried split string like this but its not working.

If `sneha@@@@pai` is the input, the output should be `sneha pai`

is this correct way to split string please help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.splitstringcheck(
    IN inputstr text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    delimeter text;  
    elems text;
  BEGIN
    
   delimeter := '@@@@';
   
   elems := string_to_array(inputstr, delimeter);
  END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: A procedure isn't meant to return anything, you need a function

Comment: Exactly @a_horse_with_no_name, or add an output parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: A function can be integrated into any SQL statement e.g. as part of a SELECT passing a column as the input or an UPDATE statement to change a column value. That's not possible with a procedure, so I doubt making this a procedure would be helpful in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You used `string_to_array` function that is gonna return you an array, not splitted string in a way you want.

Result of the function string_to_array in your case is probably one dimensional array with two columns: `{sneha,pai}`. And its correct, but its not a function you should use here.

For this specific case you could use simpliest replace to achieve your goal.

For example:

```
 select replace('sneha@@@@pai','@@@@',' ')
```

So your code could look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.splitstringcheck(
    IN inputstr text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    delimeter text;  
    elems text;
  BEGIN
    
   delimeter := '@@@@';
   
   elems := replace(inputstr, delimeter,' ');
  END
$BODY$;
```

What is more, remember that stored procedure cannot return value.
So either change stored procedure to function, or add an output parameter to the actual stored procedure.